# Setting the div height size equal to frame size height

Tags: html, css

I have 3 html pages displaying in a main single html page. [image]

I am using frameset to display all 3 pages into main page. top page contains a table placed under div (id=frame1). I want to set the height of table equal to the height of the top frame (ResultDetails.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <frameset frameborder="1" rows="70%, *">
      <frame src="ProjectInfo/ResultDetails.html" name="Content"/>
      <html>
         <frameset frameborder="1" cols="50%, *">
            <frame src="ProjectInfo/ProjectDetails.html" />
            <frame src="ProjectInfo/VariableDetails.html" name="Content"/>
         </frameset>
   </frameset>
   </html>
```

For div i am using following css.

```
#frame1{float:left;width:70%;height:400px;overflow:auto;}
```

The height of the frame may vary for different screen resolutions. How can I fix this.

Comment: How about using `height: 100%;`?

Comment: @Teemu If I set the height: 100%; and if the table contains more no. of rows, then in order to use the horizontal scroll bar of the table to see the full row content(say row 1's content), I have to scroll down completely, by that time the row 1 will be not visible. So I can not use height:100%;

Comment: @That was just a guess. Please show the relevant CSS and HTML within the frame, this `frameset` snippet is pretty useless, when solving your problem.

Comment: @Teemu Please find the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UGHXv/). Here u can see, to see the row 6th content, we have to scroll down completely, by that time, 6th row will not be visible. There are few more issues i have which will get fixed if I am able to set the height of table equals to the height of frame.

Comment: Hmm... there's so much of everything in your demo... A [simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GHVR/1/) of what you probably need.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks a lot dude. This one resolved the issue.